# How to permanently change Gemfile in each new rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile, therubyracer

How can I permanently change what is in the Gemfile when I create a new rails app.

The problem I have is that every time I create a new rails app, I get an `execjs error` when I run `'rails server'` inside of the app. After searching on stackoverflow for hours on what could be the problem I found out that `'therubyracer'` is commented out by a '#' in the Gemfile by default every time I create a new rails app.

How can I permanently change the Gemfile so that I can get rid of the `'#'` in front of `'gem therubyracer'` once, so that I don't have to open the Gemfile every single time that I create a new rails app to get rid of the `'#'`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#application-templates

Comment: Not quite, I don't want it to ask the user for input of yes or no to put in the gem, I just want to permanently get rid of the '#' so that I don't have to get rid of it in the Gemfile every time I make a new rails app.

Comment: @user43564, you are not required to ask questions.  Did you follow the template details link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html.  See section 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `nodejs` as the javascript runtime and it is better than rubyracer in memory. The `execjs error` would be fixed for any number of projects with the default Gemfile.

This is how you install in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-dev npm
```

If you want your Gemfile to include the particular line every time, you should use template as suggested in the other answer. To make it default, you could configure your .railrc to include that template every time.